# Empty xml element confusion - HTML

Tags: html, xml

Here are two html snippets:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    bar
  </body>
</html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <style type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    bar
  </body>
</html>
```

Try rendering in Firefox, Chrome or IE - the two snippets render differently! But I thought both versions of an empty element are the same? (The style element)

Comment: @keshlam, SGML is not HTML’s predecessor. HTML4 is an _implementation_ of SGML. The same as XHTML is an implementation of XML. HTML5 allows serialization in HTML (which it defines on how to do it) or in XML (which is defined in the XML spec).

Comment: [Typo corrected] HTML is not actually an XML language; it's based on SGML, which is XML's predecessor. (The XML-based version is XHTML.) Unfortunately I can't tell you why HTML is distinguishing between these two cases without diving deep into the spec, so I'll have to let someone else give you a real answer. (Sorry, I intended to make this a comment rather than an answer...)

Comment: @keshlam, not entirely correct these days: HTML5 is not SGML-based any more. :-P

Comment: When they changed the direction for HTML5 I stopped tracking it ... It still isn't XML-based, right?

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML Specification end tag is required for `STYLE` element.

> **[14.2.3 Header style information: the STYLE element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3)**
>
> Start tag: required, End tag: required

So self-closed version of `style` is not correct HTML document part.

Answer (score 1):

In XML it would be valid, but you call your snippets HTML, where it is not. – In HTML5 for example (serialized as HTML, not as XML), you didn’t close the style element yet (slash is ignored).

Answer (score 0):

When served as text/html, they are parsed with an HTML parser, which treats `<style type="text/css"/>` just as a typo for `<style type="text/css">` (i.e., ignores the slash before the tag close). This makes the rest of the document part of the `style` element and thus ignored. – This is the reason why XHTML 1.0, [appendix C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines), recommends that the “self-closing” syntax (aka. “minimized syntax”) be used only for elements with EMPTY declared content.

When served as genuine XHTML, with an XML content type, they are processed identically, by XML rules. However, in the absence of an `xmlns` attribute, they are treated just as generic XML without a style, so in practice the browsers just display the XML code as-is.